# Facebook App: What defines a "user"?

Tags: web-applications, facebook

I have a Facebook Application which is ready to be submitted to the Application Directory, but before I submit, it says " Your application must have at least 5 total users or 10 monthly active users before you can submit it to the Application Directory".

I have had many users navigate to the canvas page and use the iframe to browse the site and I also have many users that have "Liked" the Facebook App.

But it still says I have "0" users. So my questions is...what defines a user? How does that number increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means *average* visiting of your site each month. This information is available in application Info page which can be accessed like this:

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

You need to replace `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` with your application id (which can be figured out by going to http://www.facebook.com/developers and then choosing your application settings from there) and on that page will you see **Information** box which will tell you the number of average users visiting your site.

This number varies because it depends on how many users visit your site each month.

Comment: How is the Facebook system notified about visits to my website? Is it only counting users that use the website through the Canvas page iframe?

Comment: @charles_har: The users are counted when they are on facebook or in other words, using your website/app within facebook not navigating away to your site.

Comment: Okay, so that means that users are counted when they use the application's canvas page, correct? And how long does it usually take for the number of users to be updated?

Comment: @charles_har: That's correct as for updating, i am not 100% sure about it.